Python & simplekml module cannot save a file
I have a text file I'm trying to process that contains 2 pieces of data, and put that into a kml file for use in google earth.
The text file has repeating lines that look like this:
302201300410005,$GPRMC,142003.800,V,4340.4448,N,07924.9643,W,0.00,187.31,060919,,,N,V*16
302201300410005,+CCI: 3022013,-32,99.9,32,412.3125,78,27,42,-68

The line with $GPRMC is the output of a GPS receiver, the line with +CCI is the output of a radio receiver with various parameters I'm trying to log.
The intent is to generate a kml file with every lat/long point marked with the radio receiver data in the description of the point.
The primary issue I've run into is that I can't for the life of me get the kml file generated. I'm more or less following the simplekml tutorial using:
kml.save=('file.kml')

Now I've tried just a file name and using a full path but no file is generated. No error output either, not sure whats going on.
I have used print(kml.kml()) and there is the expected output, not sure why the file isn't saving.
I'm not a programmer, i use python because it's (generally) easy for me to automate some of the more monotonous things.
Code:
#import LA_names
import os
import csv
import simplekml

ccilist = ("MNI","RSSI","BER","LA","Freq","C1","nLA","nC2","nRSSI")
latlong = False
data = False
desc = ''

fp=input('Enter file path: ')
check_fp = os.path.isfile(fp)

kml = simplekml.Kml(open=1)

single_point = kml.newpoint(name="World",coords=[(0.0,0.0)])

if check_fp == True:
    with open(fp) as file_obj:
        reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
        for row in reader_obj:

            if '$GPRMC' in row:
                latlong = False
                lat = int(str(row[4])[:2])
                lat_mm = float(str(row[4])[2:])
                lat = lat + (lat_mm/60)
                if row[5] == 'S':
                    lat = -abs(lat)
                
                long = int(str(row[6])[:3])                
                long_mm = float(str(row[4])[2:])
                long = long + (long_mm/60)
                if row[7] == 'W':
                    long = -abs(long)
                latlong = True
                #print(f"LAT:{lat}\tLONG:{long}")

            if '+CCI: 3022013' in row:
                
                desc = f"RSSI:{row[2]}dBm\nLA:{row[4]}\nFreq:{row[5]}MHz\nC1:{row[6]}\nnLA:{row[7]}\nnC2:{row[8]}\nnRSSI:{row[9]}dBm"
                data = True

            if latlong == True and data == True:
                
                pnt = kml.newpoint()
                pnt.description = desc
                pnt.coords = [(long, lat)]
                pnt.shape = 'circle'
                latlong = data = False

    kml.save=('Test.kml')
    
    #print (kml.kml())
        
      
else:
    print ("File Not Found")


kml.save=('Test.kml') That is the wrong way to call the save function.  I have trouble believing that's what the tutorial said to do.  The correct way is kml.save('Test.kml')

It does not (nowhere on the tutorial site can you find .save = ( regardless of whitespace). Voting to close as a typo as a result.

You are both correct, that was my problem. While do feel a bit dumb for this being the problem, i wasn't seeing it staring at my own code. I do appreciate you pointing this out. Thanks
